# VSCode REACT Native - No errors thrown for not imported modules

Tags: javascript, react-native, visual-studio-code, error-handling

Basically my problem is:

**Vscode treats unknown variables as "any" and does not show any error unless I run it in Expo.**

As you can see below in the screenchot:
[image]

I don't understand why there is no errors thrown. Does anyone have any ideas ?
Thanks in advance for your help !
Yann

Answer (score 1):

Hope your'e using eslint as static code analyser,
If so please Check if it's extension installed. if not please install it form here [Eslint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint)

If already installed and set up has been done then might be issue with it's configuration. you can find it out the configuration issues from

***VSCode -> terminal -> Output -> Select the Eslint from the output tab dropdown***

Eslint Server status whether it has Started or not and also the issues will be shown.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, now I got my ESlint correctly installed but it remains that Vscode treats unknown variables as "any" :/